# What's the relationship between vendor, package, module and namespaces?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, package, vendor

Let's take the `Contacts` module inside my Magento 1.7 installation.

```
$ pwd
/var/www/vhosts/myproject/magento-1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts
```

I know `Contacts` is the module, but is `Mage` the package, or the vendor? Then what's `core`? I'll heard them being described as 'code pools', but still not very clear.

And how does this relate to namespacing? (if it's relevant at all?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mage is the vendor. Core is the code pool that all core/default functionality goes into. Third party modules go in the community code pool and work you create should go in the local code pool.

So if you made a module it would be in app/code/local/dayuloli/modulename/.

Comment: So there's no concept of a 'package'?

Comment: I guess you could consider the modulename the package. So one vendor could have multiple packages like what you see inside the mage directory